# How can i make my java program to listen for messages from web application?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a GUI program in java. In the gui there is a textfield. I would like this program to listen all the time for any messages-events from a web application and to print the message in the textfield. Any idea how can i do this?

Comment: Yes, you listen to the messages - only you or the application developers will know where they are sent - and process them...

Comment: Is it your web application?

Comment: because i am new at this, do you have any sample?the web application isn't mine but the java GUI is mine

Comment: Are you/server using any messaging systems like JMS /AMQP ?

Comment: no.any suggestion what to do?